# Can any non-Terrago products produce geopdfs recognized by the Terrago toolbar in Acrobat?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geopdf, global-mapper

Neither ArcMap nor GlobalMapper seem to be produce geopdfs that are recognized by the Terrago toolbar. Can anything besides Terrago products produce geopdfs that the Toolbar will accept?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [MapInfo Professional from Pitney Bowes](http://www.pbinsight.com/products/location-intelligence/applications/mapping-analytical/mapinfo-professional/).

This product integrates a [virtual PDF printer that is capable of producing geo-registered PDF files](https://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter/features/) using the format defined by Adobe in its [Acrobat Supplement to ISO 32000](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf).

The Terrago Toolbar can read both formats, the one defined by them (Terrago) and the one defined by Adobe.

Answer (score -2):

GeoMedia GeoPDF Publisher does this.  It is an add-on that runs with GeoMedia Professional.  HexagonGeospatial.com